# Is there any way to override back button?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to override back button in browser so that, for example, if a user came from A.aspx to B.aspx, when he tries to go back from B.aspx it should go to Home.aspx not A.aspx.

Is there any way to accomplish that? It doesn't matter if it's using ASP, C#, JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: If this may be accomplished, it would only be possibly through JavaScript.

Comment: This can also be accomplished on the server by using sessions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use JQuery to catch the browser back (popstate) event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState('forward', null, null);
    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
      window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Track the last page in the user's ASP.NET session.  This can be done In C# by setting the "last page" on the session whenever an aspx page loads. When ASP.NET A.aspx loads, check the last page in the session before setting it.  If it was B, redirect to home.

A guide to using session state in ASP.NET Web Forms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution to prevent it but you can detect it and send them back where they came from with JS.

place this on the page where you don't want them to get back

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }

     setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);

     window.onunload = function () { null };
     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like some MV* frameworks,(in single-page-app) they use `location.pushState`for **>=IE10**  browsers,and `window.onhashchange` for others to listening hash change.

So you can listen the back button by listen hash change.